# Overloading operator== but it doesn't get called (comparing pointers?)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the == operator to compare between two objects. For some reason the overloaded handler is never called.

```
class gxCallback
{
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const gxCallback &aOther) const
    {
        // This is never called
        return true;
    } 
};

typedef std::vector < gxCallback* > CallbackList;

void gxObservable::Fire( gxCallback *aCallback )
{
    CallbackList::iterator iCallback;

    for ( iCallback = mCallbacks.begin(); iCallback != mCallbacks.end(); ++iCallback )
    {
        if ( aCallback == *iCallback ) // The comparison is never made via the overloaded ==
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Never had an idea what Symbian is until I saw your comment. Why would you think so?

Comment: @lzhaki the naming convention you use closely resembles the Symbian coding standard guidelines

Comment: Interesting. I came up with this convention myself, but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling it on a pointer, not the object. You'll have to compare the object with the one the iterator is referencing:

```
if (*aCallback == **iCallback)
```

You also have to make sure the "pointers" hold something before you dereference them.

Comment: Oh boy.. this was my suspicion and I have tried your solution before posting the question. But I got Segmentation error. This is due to the fact I've removed a check if aCallback is NULL for debugging. But you ensuring me this has lead me to realise all that, and no doubt is the correct answer. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing pointers rather than the objects themselves.